# run a thread after another finishes in a button click

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, textbox, buttonclick

I want to combine 2 different button click events in one button click. I have two threads in these two button click events to update text box in winform. When I am trying to combine these two buttons, threads run synchronously but I need thread2 runs after thread1 finishes. How can I do that? I tried doing thread1.start than thread2.start but it did not work because all click event executes at once. Is there anyone to help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.Net 4:**
If you are using .net 4 or later, take a look at Tasks, particularly the [ContinueWith method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).   This is a more uniform approach that is much better.

**.Net 1-3.5:**
If you are already managing the threading yourself, probably the best way is to have only one thread.

```
new Thread(DoJob1And2).Start()
```

Where the methods are defined as:

```
void DoJob1And2()
{
   try
   {
       Job1();
   }
   finally
   {
       Job2();
   }
}

void Job1()
{
   // Do job 1
}

void Job2()
{
   // Do job 2
}
```

Comment: I tried to write in one functions but I did not use try finally and I didn't use a new thread to call DoJob1And2. It works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like

```
new Thread(() =>
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }).Start();
```

or better using TPL

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1())   
            .ContinueWith(t => Method2());
```